# Ajax request, asp.net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I've got controller method

```
public ActionResult Products(int shopId)
    {
        var products = db.Products.Where(x => x.ShopId == shopId).ToList();             
        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
             type: 'GET', 
             url: 'Home/Products', 
             data: 'shopId=' + shopId, 
             success: function(data){              
                 $('.results').html(data);
                 productList = data;
             }

 });
```

Data go to controller. Then I need go to new view. But it doesn't work. I need smth like this. Is it problem with GET/POST request?

```
public ActionResult Products(int shopId)
    {
        var products = db.Products.Where(x => x.ShopId == shopId).ToList();             
        return View(products);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `url: '@Url.Action("Products", "Home")',` so your url is correctly generated and `data: { shopId: shopId },` so the data is correctly sent. And what do you mean _go to a new view_? The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Ajax calls do not redirect. If you want to go to another view, then do not use ajax.

Comment: Thank you. So ajax send data to the controller. Then I'd like to go to the view. Is it possible?

Comment: No. As I explained, ajax calls do not redirect. Just do a normal form submit if you want to redirect to another view

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ajax` in this case. You can redirect to the view like following.

```
window.location='Home/Products?shopId=' + shopId;
```